# Show that there are irreducible polynomials of every degree in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

There is this problem that I would like to ask for any verification whether my answer is correct.

Edited: Thanks @andybenji.

> Show that for any $n\ge1$, there exists an irreducible polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$ of degree $n$.

My answer:
For degree n=0, a non-zero constant is a unit, hence it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.
For all $n\ge1$, $x^n+2$ satisfies Eisenstein's Criterion with p=2, therefore it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

I am particularly doubtful about the case of degree 0. Is it correct that a non-zero constant is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$? I saw my friend's note which says there are no irreducible polynomials of degree 0. Which one is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: You've got it.  The question was poorly stated.  It should be 
"Show that there are irreducible polynomials of degree $n \geq 1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$."

Comment: @andybenji I guess you mean different thing. My question asked to show for all n, there are irreducible polynomials in Q[X]. Not there are irreducible polynomials for some degree n. Maybe that clarifies your statement. Correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: @user70346 Alas, my clarification wasn't very clear.  A reformulation could be "Show that, for any $n \geq 1$, there exists an irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree $n$."

Comment: @andybenji. Thanks for the reformulation. I have edited it in the post.

Comment: The point of the reformulation was that it (intentionally) excludes constant (degree 0) polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, the question was unclear, and a possible restatement would be

> Show that, for any $n \geq 1$, there exists an irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree $n$.

To address the actual question, units are not irreducible.  The definition of irreducible states

> An element $f \in A$ is called *irreducible* if $f$ is not zero and not a unit, and for any expression $gh = f$, either $g$ or $h$ is a unit.

So it would, technically, be correct to say there are no irreducible polynomials of degree 0 over a field.

Comment: Oh yes, you are correct. I have overlooked such a critical thing in the definition. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's an important part and helps you to avoid headaches later on :^)